# Get a tally of tapes in an IBM 3500 tape library

Tags: command-line-interface, tape

My organization uses an IBM 3584 Tape Library. I want to know how many tapes are currently loaded into it and how many slots are available in the library total (or at least remaining). IBM's website suggests to either use the web interface (not installed/active) or ask the operator panel on the front which will stall all active operations until it conducts a complete inventory. Surely it has a running list of the tapes in each frame, right? Anyone know the CLI command to find this?

Comment: What OS is the host running?

Comment: We're running on AIX.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found an answer after some more digging.

```
dsmadmc -id=**** -pa=**** 'query libvolume' | egrep -c 'Private|Scratch'
```

That will return the number of tapes in the system and a little one-time counting tells me how much capacity our configuration has. `Capactiy - count = remaining`

Hope this helps someone.